# Can PowerShell alias keywords?

Tags: powershell

I was looking into the `Set-Alias` command, which:

> Creates or changes an alias for a cmdlet or other command in the current PowerShell session.

So I thought, hey why not "yeet" errors, just for fun (not in srs code!), tried it:

```
Set-Alias -Name Yeet -Value throw
Get-Alias -Name Yeet
```

`Get-Alias` reports that it's created the alias.

```
CommandType  Name            Version    Source
Alias        Yeet -> throw
```

Attempting to "yeet" an error:

```
yeet "oh sh*t"
```

Returns the following:

```
yeet : The term 'throw' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

Is this because it's a keyword, and not a command? You can see the alias has worked. What's the best workaround? A Function that simply takes a param and rethrows it seems pretty boring.

Comment: As I'm not on a Windows system can you confirm that if you do the same thing with `throw` results in a different statement?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, `throw "works fine on my pc"` behaves as expected.

Comment: This was what I meant, but I see you have an answer by now.

Comment: @creyD powershell runs on linux, btw.

Comment: I'm using macOS and I just saw that there is even a release for this. But thank you anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot alias something that does not stand on its own, including function definitions.  All the alias commands do are sub your alias for a callable.

e.g.

```
function test { throw 'test' }
Set-Alias myalias test
```

meanwhile

```
Set-Alias myalias { throw 'test' }
```

will not work.  It will cast the scriptblock to a string and then calling the alias will subsequently fail.

**In general**, if your sub doesn't show up in `Get-Command`, you cannot alias to it.

---

> What's the best workaround? A Function that simply takes a param and rethrows it seems pretty boring.

Boring is functional:

```
function yeet { throw $args }
```

Comment: I had a feeling this was the answer, although bonus points for attempting to alias a script block. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @DanielMorritt Certainly is.  [Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: You could use `Set-Alias yeet Write-Error` for a similar effect

Comment: I found that, but for all intents and purposes, it _did_ add the alias (according to `Get-Alias` anyway as shown in my question).  I read that doc earlier (and the `Get-Help` manual), and couldn't find any explicit exceptions, I think your previous description is the closest we'll get to.

Comment: @DanielMorritt [From the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-5.1#alternate-names-for-commands-with-parameters): `You can assign an alias to a cmdlet, script, function, or executable file. You cannot assign an alias to a command and its parameters.`  I don't think they considered aliasing in a programmatic sense, but in a shell sense (like bash).

Comment: I think the main reason they don't allow scripting keywords as aliases is because it's bad programming style to include aliases in a script because they add possible ambiguity between systems. It could also raise a security/stability issue as someone could possibly change the meaning of a script file by defining aliases outside of it.